# Dusting off rust of Programming and Logic

Tags: java

So I am working on a homework assignment for a Programming and Logic class II. I did well in the first class but that happened to be about 3 semesters ago and a different teacher. I am beyond lost on this first assignment. Any help would be great as to what I am missing.

Write a Java program to demonstrate using command line arguments to convert numeric quantities with a certain radix (counting base) to base ten numbers. You will employ the use of String methods indexOf() and substring() as well as the Integer method parseInt().

The strings in args will be the form “value:radix” where value is expressed with digits appropriate to the radix.

So “16384:10” is 16384 as a base 10 number.
Use indexOf() to find the colon and gather the number and the radix using substring(). These values can be used to make a call to parseInt() to convert the numbers to base 10.

If the provided command line arguments were:
4eb:16 10110110:2 407:8 2048:10

Output should be similar to:
4eb base 16 is 1259 base 10 10110110 base 2 is 182 base 10 407 base 8 is 263 base 10 2048 base 10 is 2048 base 10

So what I have so far. Compiles but cant get it to take the args and I know I am not getting the parseint right or radix I think.

```
public class D1 {
public static void main(String[] args) 
{ int x, col; String number, radix;

for (x=0; x < args.length; x++) {
  col = args[x].indexOf(":");
  number = args[x].substring(0,col);
  radix = args[x].substring(col + 1);
  int base1 = Integer.parseInt(number, 16);
  System.out.println( number + " base " + radix + " is " + base1 + " base 10"); }
} }
```

Comment: What output are you getting, and how does it differ from the expected output? Edit your question.

Comment: "I can't get it to take the args" doesn't give us enough information.  Please tell it what you expect it to do, and what it's doing instead.

Comment: Sorry. The question was not clear to me so what I was trying to get out as well was confusing me to me.  I needed to convert radix into an int to work with parseInt.

Comment: hint:  You need to parse _two_ numbers for each given argument:  First you need to parse the radix (i.e., whatever came after the colon) as a base 10 number, and then you need to parse whatever came before the colon using the value that you got for the radix.  System.out.println(...) is your friend.  Use it to print out `the `number` string and the `radix` string to make sure that you are getting those right.

Comment: Also, don't be afraid of long, descriptive variable names:  I would have variables with names like, `numberAsString`, `radixAsString`, `numberAsInt`, `radixAsInt`.

Answer (score 0):

As the `parseInt` takes a `int` as its second parameter you need to convert your `String radix` to an int

```
radix = args[x].substring(col + 1);
int base1 = Integer.parseInt(number, Integer.parseInt(radix));
```

Comment: damn, always something simple I missed. That did it and makes complete sense now that I see it. Thanks!!!

Comment: Always the simple stuff eh.  if my answer helped please upvote and/or accept